# Downloading a file from server to client

Tags: php, download

I have seen a lot of answers that seem to answer this although they don't seem to work for me. All of the answers use readfile() and that is supposed to bring up a download box although for me it just always prints in console.
Here is the code that I have.

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="\\'.basename($path).'\"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));       
    readfile($path);
```

This code is taken from both the php readfile docs and a multitude of stack overflow questions that have this as the accepted answer. Also the file is saved outside of the webroot although the path is correctly generated and as far as I can tell it gets there correctly because it prints things in the console window.

Also the way that I call the php file is from a js file using ajax.

Comment: _"Also the way that I call the php file is from a js file using ajax"_ ... and there's your problem ... You can not trigger a download dialog from a _background_ request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on CBroe's comment:

If you direct your browser to the download URL, your browser should correctly interpret the download headers and present a dialog box for downloading. This will not occur when your Javascript queries this URL in the background.

One way of presenting a download dialog without redirecting the user's browser location is to load the download URL in an iFrame on the page.

Comment: The iframe thing should not really be necessary though; all modern browsers keep displaying the current page when you "redirect" them to a resource that triggers a download dialog AFAIK. So for a GET request a simple `location.href=...` should do; if you need to trigger the download with a POST request, then a form that gets submitted via JS can do the trick.